# Realtime Updating for .log file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

Im trying to refresh a .log file every second to show instant/realtime update straight to the webpage. My HTML is as follows

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="console" style="background-color:black;color:green;overflow:auto;width:500px;height:700px;">
</div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $("#console").load('/log/latest.log');
  }, 1000;
});
```

**File Setup**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use node.js and websocket to resolve this requirement?

You just need to setup a simple node.js server and enable websocket service.In your html page should also add a websocket client.

After that, node.js server helps you to check the log file and websocket helps you to update the results in realtime.If you do this,even if a more complicated business comes out,you can also resolve it very quickly.

Enjoy node.js ;-)

Comment: Ive never used Node.JS so I figured id go just with the regular ol simple Javascript. Will look into this though :)

Comment: Just follow the websocket tutorial.5 minutes later,you can use node.js and websocket.Aha.

Comment: Using http://hastebin.com/jedejefola.vhdl its returning http://hastebin.com/jeqevenufu.rb

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you're missing `)` to close `setInterval` function, try to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#console").load('/log/latest.log');
    }, 1000); // <-- Here
});
```

Comment: And according to the HTML missing a `#console` element too

Comment: I think he's not posting full HTML markup since it's stop at `<body>` tag

Comment: If you with to make sure that you don't get a cached version append '?T=' + new Date().getTime(); this will make sure that every request has a unique url!

Comment: @Felix Didn't fix what I needed, but thank you for helping :). Atleast what you have so far.